# "Get-IISAppPool" not recognised when script is run via Invoke-Command in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, iis-8

I'm trying to pull back a list of app pools on one of our servers. I am running the `Get-IISAppPool` command. This seems to be working locally however when I call a script via Invoke-Command on a remote machine the command is no longer recognized

I have tried to include modules such as:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

or

```
Import-Module IISAdministration
```

and these are not fixing the problem.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: that likely means the module is not in the module path for the account that is running the script. have you checked `$env:PSModulePath` for that account?

Comment: If I'm running via Invoke-Command would that not mean it would be the same user as running locally? Running that command passed in like so: ```Invoke-Command -ComputerName "[SERVER_NAME]" -ScriptBlock {$env:PSModulePath}``` returns the same modules as running this command locally. With a single SQL module path being an exception.

Comment: that means it SHOULD be found & loaded automatically. [*sigh ...*] you may need to explicitly use the path to the module in your scriptblock. other than that, i am stuck for ideas.

Comment: Could it be permissions based i.e. does Invoke-Command run powershell as if it were in administrator mode?

Comment: from what i can tell, it runs at the level of the calling account. if you are running "as admin" locally, then the account will have that priv on the remote box IF you have not run into the "double hop: problem.

Comment: Hmm if it were a double hop issue would I not be getting access denied rather than an exception? I can run other commands in the script I have created, it looks to be just tied to this module. I will try pass the module path in and see if it continues to hit the CommandNotFoundException. Thanks.

Comment: good luck ... i am out of ideas & will go back to lurking ... [*grin*]

Comment: Looks like you may be on to something, just attempted to import the module via a separate script which also runs the failed command and got a new exception ```The specified module 'IISAdministration' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.```

Comment: that does seem to mean there is a problem with the path as seen by that account on that system. i don't know enuf about that module to know why, tho. [*blush*]

Comment: What is the script? Don't everyone guess please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not on the IIS Server, then no, those are not available. 
So, set an Implicit remote session and try it again.

```
# Implicit Remoting - creds must an admin on the target box.
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName IIS01 -Credential "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"

Get-PSSession

 # Results

 Id Name       ComputerName    State         ConfigurationName     Availability
 -- ----       ------------    -----         -----------------     ------------
  2 Session2   iis01           Opened        Microsoft.PowerShell     Available

Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {
Get-Command -Name '*IIS*'
}

# Results
CommandType     Name                           ModuleName          PSComputerName
-----------     ----                           ----------          --------------
Function        IIS:                           WebAdministration   iis01 
Cmdlet          Clear-IISCentralCertProvider   IISAdministration   iis01 
Cmdlet          Clear-IISConfigCollection      IISAdministration   iis01 
Cmdlet          Disable-IISCentralCertProvider IISAdministration   iis01 
Cmdlet          Disable-IISSharedConfig        IISAdministration   iis01 
Cmdlet          Enable-IISCentralCertProvider  IISAdministration   iis01 
Cmdlet          Enable-IISSharedConfig         IISAdministration   iis01 
Cmdlet          Export-IISConfiguration        IISAdministration   iis01 
Cmdlet          Get-IISAppPool                 IISAdministration   iis01 
...
```